# Problem with Controller and FXML, Grid Pane is Null

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem with fxml controller communication.
I have App class which is a controller:

```
package org.example.gui;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.example.Game;
import org.example.Main;
import java.io.IOException;

public class App extends Application {
    private Game game;
    private MapVisualiser mapV;

    @FXML
    private GridPane mapGridPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/main-scene.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 1530, 790);
        stage.setResizable(true);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.setTitle("GymSnake");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        this.game = new Game();
        this.mapV = new MapVisualiser(game.getMap(),mapGridPane);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

and a fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.example.gui.App">
    <GridPane fx:id="mapGridPane" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT">
    </GridPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

Also the MapVisualiser code to make sure everything is working fine

```
public MapVisualiser(Map map, GridPane gridPane) {
        this.map = map;
        this.gridPane = gridPane;
        calculateColumnsAndRowsSize();
    }

    private void calculateColumnsAndRowsSize() {
        int squareHeight = (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * Configuration.GRID_HEIGHT / map.getN());
        int squareWidth  = (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * Configuration.GRID_WIDTH / map.getN());
        this.sideLengthOfSquarePx = Math.max(40, Math.max(squareWidth, squareHeight));
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(sideLengthOfSquarePx));
        gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(sideLengthOfSquarePx));
    }
```

I don't understand why my grid pane returns null
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.getColumnConstraints()" because "this.gridPane" is null

Please help

Comment: _I have App class which is a controller_ don't ..

Comment: don't  make a controller that extends Application class

Comment: This is an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) for the reasons given in comments.